# What software did Joel use to get this type of drawing?

Tags: windows, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software for designing prototypes (a raw design) of user interfaces](https://superuser.com/questions/33442/software-for-designing-prototypes-a-raw-design-of-user-interfaces)

Hello

I have no graphic skills and would like to create drawings that look like this

[image: drawing]

i.e. it gives the impression that it was hand-drawn rather than done with a computer.

Do you know what Windows application lets users create drawings like this? PhotoShop + drawing skills?

Comment: The second question is a duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/33442/software-for-designing-prototypes-a-raw-design-of-user-interfaces (and its accepted answer is also the correct one for the first here).

Answer (score 6):

99% sure it would be [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/) or something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156937/do-you-know-an-alternative-to-balsamiq-mockups-for-wireframe-building).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like they were done with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)